# Google Sheet Script cycling through a sheet and adding new rows and text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created my first function in google sheets. Basically I got it to work the way I want it to but it hits a max execution time limit. I posted the code below, I'm sure there are a few ways to optimize it so it can run faster.

The code basically cycles through records in a sheet to add image filenames. There are six image filenames per product and sometimes I need to add new rows to list all the filenames, like in the following screenshot:

[image: file structure]

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var c = 1;

  for (var i=1; i<values.length; i++) {

    c = 1;

    do {
    c = c + 1;
    i = i + 1;
    } while (values[i+1][13] == values[i][13]);

    while (c < 6) {
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(i+1,1);
    c = c + 1;
    i = i + 1;
    sheet.getRange(i+1,1).setValue(values[i-1][0]);
    }

    range = sheet.getDataRange();
    values = range.getValues();


    if(c <= 6) {
      sheet.getRange(i-4,25).setValue(values[i-5][13] + "_main.jpg");
      sheet.getRange(i-3,25).setValue(values[i-5][13] + "_detail.jpg");
      sheet.getRange(i-2,25).setValue(values[i-5][13] + "_detail1.jpg");
      sheet.getRange(i-1,25).setValue(values[i-5][13] + "_detail2.jpg");
      sheet.getRange(i,25).setValue(values[i-5][13] + "_side.jpg");
      sheet.getRange(i+1,25).setValue(values[i-5][13] + "_back.jpg");
    }

    if(c > 6) {
      sheet.getRange(i-c+2,25).setValue(values[i-c+2][13] + "_main.jpg");
      sheet.getRange(i-c+3,25).setValue(values[i-c+2][13] + "_detail.jpg");
      sheet.getRange(i-c+4,25).setValue(values[i-c+2][13] + "_detail1.jpg");
      sheet.getRange(i-c+5,25).setValue(values[i-c+2][13] + "_detail2.jpg");
      sheet.getRange(i-c+6,25).setValue(values[i-c+2][13] + "_side.jpg");
      sheet.getRange(i-c+7,25).setValue(values[i-c+2][13] + "_back.jpg");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**One Big Batch Update instead of a bunch of small ones**

Your problem is that each call to `sheet.getRange` take quite a lot of time (~100 ms) relative to average run of the mill code. When you do it 10 times per loop with the loop running 100 times, your code will run a few minutes when it could be taking only a few seconds.

The way you speed it up is by taking all those little updates (each `sheet.getRange` call) and combining them into one big batch update, as recommended in this [article by google about best practices with google scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices).

For example, instead of doing this:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(1);
sheet.getRange(2, 1).setValue(2);
sheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(3);
sheet.getRange(2, 2).setValue(4);
```

Do this:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).setValue([[1, 2], [3, 4]]);
```

**How to do it with your code**

First load all the data you need in as few I/O calls as possible which you do with `sheet.getDataRange().getValues()`.

Next make all the necessary calculations without reading and writing to the spreadsheet. If you need, you can use a two-dimensional array to act in place of the spreadsheet:

```
data = [["A", "tire.jpg"], ["B", "fire.jpg"]];
data[i+2][c-1] = values[3][8] + "_main.jpg";
```

When you're finished you can write the `data` to the spreadsheet all at once:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```